# Finding the address of a char array in the stack

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

I am trying to understand the layout of the stack and how memory is allocated.

I have the following program and I want to know the starting address of the `buffer` array, if suppose the stack starts at address 12000 (for instance).

```
void function( int a, int b ) {     
    char buffer[ 512 ]; 
} 

void main() {
    function( 1, 2 );
}
```

Comment: You'll have to compiler the code and inspect the binary (or print out the address in `function`). There's nothing in standard C that will let you calculate that address, it's completely compiler/platform dependent.

Comment: @1336087 Stacks usually grow downwards, and you haven't considered main's call of function (and it depends on how big addresses are).

Comment: "I want to know the starting address of the buffer array" You can't, because you don't know what your particular version of your particular compiler decides to do with your particular program at your particular optimization level at this particular day of the week. Maybe it doesn't allocate any space for `buffer` at all because it's unused. Or maybe it allocates it on the heap because it's Sunday, and because it can.

Comment: I am using Fedora 32-bit. Will gdb help me in getting to know the full stack?

Comment: @ooga: It is architecture specific.

Comment: char usually occupies 1 byte in memory. So will char buffer [ 512 ] occupy 512 bytes in memory? So theoretically, the starting address of buffer will be 12000-512 , am I correct?

Comment: @user3257977 it's compiler/architecture dependant, the address is most likely 12000-512 +/- some bytes. Check it out with a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address of a non-static local variable in a function depends on the state of the stack (the value of the SP register) at the point in execution when the function is invoked.

In simple words, `buffer` may have a different address every time `function` is invoked.

Having emphasized that, you can use either one of the following options:

```
printf("%p", buffer); // applicable only for arrays
printf("%p",&buffer); // applicable for arrays and for non-arrays
```

Comment: So in the layout of the stack, where exactly the buffer address starts? Is it right at the start or somewhere in between or varies depending on the architecture and compiler?

Comment: @user3257977: Like I said in the answer, the address of the buffer may be different every time the function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the addresses used at run time

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function( int a, int b ) {
    int c;
    char buffer[ 512 ]; 
    int d;
    printf ("Address of a is %p\n", &a);
    printf ("Address of b is %p\n", &b);
    printf ("Address of c is %p\n", &c);
    printf ("Address of d is %p\n", &d);
    printf ("Address of buffer is %p\n", buffer);
} 

void main() {
    function( 1, 2 );
}
```